# The number of positive integral values taken by $f(x)=(x^3-11^3)^{1/3}$ over natural numbers $x$

Tags: number-theory, functions

> For $f:{\Bbb{N}}\to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=(x^3-11^3)^{1/3}$, what is the number of positive integral values $f(x)$ can take?

The first thing that came into my mind was just simply trial and error but I soon realised that it wasn't going to come handy here.   I thought maybe factoring

$$(x^3-11^3)= (x-11)(x^2 + 11x + 121)$$

might give some leads to this but I just couldn't figure something out from this.

How do I approach this? I believe there might be some kind of specific theorem or rule that helps to solve these kind of problems that I don't know of, because I just can't figure out how to start in the first place.

Comment: If $y^3=x^3-11^3$ then $11^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is $0$ by Fermat's Last Theorem. Indeed, $(x^3-11^3)^{1/3}=y \in \mathbb{N}$ would imply $y^3+11^3=x^3$, which has no solutions in the positive integers by FLT.

Comment: Of course the $n=3$ case of FLT was proved long ago and is way less complicated than the general  FLT

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)  comes to mind. However, with the hint from @lulu, we can show that the equation

$$y^3+ 11^3 = x^3$$
has no positive solutions. Otherwise, we had
$$11^3 = (x-y)(x^2+ x y + y^2)$$ and so $x-y$ is a power of $11$. If it were at least $11$, then $x^2 + x y + y^2$ must equal $11^2$, so $y=0$. Otherwise, we have $x-y=1$, so $x^3-y^3= 3y^2 + 3 y + 1\not = 11^3$ (check $\mod 3$).

Answer (score 2):

x must be 11^3 * (k^3+1), with a non-negative integer constant k, in order that f(x) will become an integer too. But x then will become 11 * (k^3+1)^(1/3). This itself will only be an integer as required, when k = 0, with f(11) = 0. This though is not a positive integral value.
=> The number of positive integer values f may take is zero.

P.S.: Third roots of negative numbers are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, there is always one of The Oldest Tricks In The Book: The difference between any other cube and $x^3$ is at least $3x^2-3x+1$, which is greater than $11^3$ for any $x \ge 25$. So if nothing else one can try all integers between 1 and 25.